# Templates shortcut change Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a way to change template completion shortcut - instead of <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (suggestions) another <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (templates) and then enter to simply press <kbd>TAB</kbd> and the template will be printed if there is only one? Or any suggestion how to make it faster? I am switching from IDEA and I am used to just press the tab..

I tried to find the shortcut in the `preferences -> general -> keys` but I haven't found a way how to set this thing specifically.

Have a nice day :-)